# Key does not exist when executing New-SelfSignedCertificate

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate

I've written a script that'll create certificates for me and that should sign them all using another certificate.

```
$dnsNames = @("example.com", "example.org")
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName $dnsNames -FriendlyName "Example Cert" -Signer Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\QWREEWRQ12123132QWEQWE123123
```

But when I run this script I get the error message *CertEnroll::CSignerCertificate::Initialize: Key does not exist. 0x8009000d (-2146893811 NTE_NO_KEY)*.

The private key is available in the certificate store and the certificate got the intended purposes of Client Authentication and Server Authentication.

What is causing this error message?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else struggling with this.

Make sure Powershell is running as Administrator (this is critical).

Remember that this only works on Windows 10, if you're trying to use the New_SelfSignedCertificate command on older OS's you'll find that it's out of date and doesn't support some of the extended parameters, some of which are very necessary e.g. multiple values for -DnsName with SANs support. I personally couldn't even get it to work on Server 2012 R2 when I wanted to create a certificate with SAN wildcards (*.mydomain.com). Just stick with the version on Windows 10 and you'll be fine ;)

Assign the Root CA you already created (I'm assuming you did this) to a variable:

```
$rootcert = ( Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My\6980327922B448834C67547B20DB8F054326F140
```

Now pass that variable into the New-SelfSignedCertificate command:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName MyDnsName,MyOtherDnsName -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Signer $rootcert -KeyUsage CertSign,CRLSign,DataEncipherment,DigitalSignature,KeyAgreement,KeyEncipherment -Type SSLServerAuthentication
```

The example above creates an SSL Certificate but you can create any of the available types by setting a different value for the -Type variable. You can also change the -KeyUsage values to the appropriate value(s). See the documentation of optional parameters here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 0):

At least [the examples](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate) enclose the path in quotes and in addition your parameter is spelled wrong (`CertStoreLocaiton` instead of `CertStoreLocation`). In addition you might have to use the `-ExistingKey` switch.

Comment: How did you decide to add those parameters? Why are you suddenly trying to add a Provider? You could try to use [Get-Certificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/get-certificate) to get the certificate you want to sign with and supply the variable as an argument to the `signer` parameter. That way you know it would be a valid object.

Comment: I read this under **-ExistingKey** *"When you use an existing key, specify values for the Container parameter, the Provider parameter, and the CertStoreLocation parameter. CertStoreLocation determines the context. The context is user or computer."*

Comment: Even without actively supplying it the default values for at least the provider should be fine. If you look at [either](http://blog.davidchristiansen.com/2016/09/howto-create-self-signed-certificates-with-powershell/) of [these](https://gist.github.com/Jaykul/b6c366c0e580f6350e0aaef55036903c) you will find that they're skipping container as well as provider.

Comment: `new-selfsignedcertificate -dnsname "testestcert" -signer (new-selfsignedcertificate -dnsname "testestroot")` works but `new-selfsignedcertificate -dnsname "testestcert" -signer $root` doesn't. Gives *Cannot find object or property. 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND)* but echoing $root shows the root cert 

Comment: The root has to me in the `My` store, omg.